# Blazor namespace Interop does not extist in the namespace

Tags: c#, namespaces, interop, assembly-references, blazor

Where do I find the assembly reference and how can I add it?

**Error Description:**

> CS0234 The type or namespace name 'Interop' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Blazor.Browser' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
>
> CS0103 The name 'RegisteredFunction' does not exist in the current context Phoneword.Client

I have a small Blazor project which I would like to run again after some time. But it seems I've deleteted the reference or something else is broken.

**Edit I:**

Blazor: 0.5.1

Target framework: .NET Standart 2.0

Comment: Which version are you using?

Answer (score 1):

'RegisteredFunction' does not exist anymore.

This is how you define a function in a JavaScript file:

```
window.exampleJsFunctions = {
  showPrompt: function (message) {
    return prompt(message, 'Type anything here');
  }
};
```

And this is how you call the function from your Blazor code:

```
using Microsoft.JSInterop;

    public class ExampleJsInterop
    {
        public static Task<string> Prompt(string message)
        {
            // Implemented in exampleJsInterop.js
            return JSRuntime.InvokeAsync<string>(
                "exampleJsFunctions.showPrompt",
                message);
        }
    }
```

Comment: FYI, Current has been removed. https://github.com/dotnet/aspnetcore/issues/8117